# Trigger action after delay

Tags: c#, async-await, xamarin.forms

I have the following code in an OnTextChanged event in a Xamarin.Forms project:

```
async void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (this.txtClientFilter.Text.Length > 4)
            {
                var client_list= App.ClientManager.GetTasksAsync(txtClientFilter.Text);
                var template = new DataTemplate(typeof(TextCell));

                template.SetBinding(TextCell.DetailProperty, "nom_ct");
                template.SetBinding(TextCell.TextProperty, "cod_ct");

                listview.ItemTemplate = template;
                listview.ItemsSource = await client_list;

            }
        }
```

As you can see, almost every keypress is trying to make a request (via a GetTaskAsync method). I don't want to fire every keypress, I would like to ignore some keypress under 1000 milliseconds.

How can I do that? I found some examples using Task.Delay() but didn't work as expected.

Comment: Use Task.Delay with CancellationToken and Cancel the old call each time before you make the new one. This way only the last keypress after 1000 ms have passed will be executed.

Comment: It is very hard to see what you've tried and "didn't work as expected", but maybe you should look into comparison operators on TimeSpan to see how long it was since last call...

Comment: As soon as developers start talking about *time*-based requirements like this, I recommend looking into Reactive Extensions (Rx). It has a steep learning curve, but is *perfect* for these kinds of problems.

Answer (score 3):

```
    private int taskId = 0;

    private async void ExecAutoComplete()
    {
        var client_list = App.ClientManager.GetTasksAsync(txtClientFilter.Text);
        var template = new DataTemplate(typeof(TextCell));

        template.SetBinding(TextCell.DetailProperty, "nom_ct");
        template.SetBinding(TextCell.TextProperty, "cod_ct");

        listview.ItemTemplate = template;
        listview.ItemsSource = await client_list;
    }

    private void TryExecute(int taskId)
    {
        if (this.taskId == taskId)
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(ExecAutoComplete));
    }

    private async void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ++taskId;
        Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith(t =>  TryExecute(taskId));
    }
```

We create unique `taskId` on each `textChange` and if after 1000ms `taskId` remains the same (no more text changes) we execute actual call.

Comment: Side note: why do you mix `async` and `ContinueWith` (short of to confuse people)?

Comment: Good point, I just kept OP `async` there as his other code may rely on it.

Comment: After some fast keypress, I got this exception: (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))

Comment: Oh right, we can't update UI from another thread. I just updated TryExecute method to run UI updates on UI thread. Give it another try.

Comment: If you used `await Task.Delay(1000); TryExecute(taskId);` (what I think @AlexeiLevenkov had in mind), there won't be a thread issue.

Comment: My C# is rusty, but isn't this still going to generate an event for every key stroke, just with a 1s latency?

Comment: Correct, but autocomplete will be only executed if `taskId` was not changed within last 1000ms which means no other key stroke fired.

Comment: Can't use  this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(ExecAutoComplete)), I have a missing assembly or library :/

Answer (score 0):

Create a `_lastClickTime` private property of type `DateTime` on your page and add this to the beginning of your button click handler:

```
if (DateTime.Now - _lastClickTime < new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1000))
{
    return;
}
_lastClickTime = DateTime.Now;
```

Have I misunderstood your question?

Comment: If 2 key presses happened quickly your logic will execute only first one but not the second one. While OP needs opposite logic - first one is ignored while second is executed.